# Lookup function working only for the referred DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, lookup

I wanted to pull nearest store details to customers in email. I have a DE with all necessary Store details along with the customer details mapped. To display the store details in an email, I used Lookup function. I have linked the lookup to Subscriber Id and it is in encrypted format. This particular field is present in both Neareststore DE and the actual sendable DE. But my Lookup function is not running as expected and correct details are populated only for StoreDE and not for others. Is there any other possibilities to display store details in the email whatever may be the DE.?

Also I need to use If else to pull 2 different contents.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Please update your question to include a sample of your code and a sample of the data in the data extensions involved.

Comment: Agreed with @AdamSpriggs, there needs to be more context for us to be able to give relevant suggestions or solutions.